# Morris chart data from a array through a for loop

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I have a morris chart in the code. I want to set data from a loop like below. 
for loop isn't working.

```
var TicketInfo =
 [{
         for(i = 0; i < data_json.RESULT.length; i++){ 
            y: 'total',
            a: data_json.RESULT[i].total_cus,
            b: data_json.RESULT[i].new_total_cus
        }
        }]
   Morris.Bar({
        element: 'morris-bar-chart',
        data: TicketInfo,
        xkey: 'y',
        ykeys: ['a','b'],
        labels: ['abc','xyz'],
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true
    });
```

Please help me to achive this.

Answer (score 3):

Just make required object and use it.

```
var morrisData = [];

$.each(data, function(key, val){
    morrisData.push({'index': key, 'Value' : val}); 
});
```

Now you will have an object that looks like this:

```
[
    { 'index' : 2, 'Value' : 25 },
    { 'index' : 3, 'Value' : 19 }
    { 'index' : 4, 'Value' : 6 }
]
```

And so on...

Then you can simply invoke Morrisand pass data:morrisData

```
Morris.Bar({
    ...
    data:morrisData
    ...
});
```